# How to use Scan and Value when working with SQL and gRPC?

Tags: sql, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Could someone explain how to properly use `Scan()` and `Value()` in the following example?

I'm trying to make use of the following examples:

- https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/2017#issuecomment-537627961
- https://github.com/travisjeffery/proto-go-sql/blob/master/_example/person_sql.go

My proto:

```
message Timestamp {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
}
message User {
  uint32 ID = 1;
  Timestamp createdAt = 2;
}
```

Code (need to fix `time.Now()`):

```
package v1

import (
        "database/sql/driver"
        "fmt"
        "time"

        "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"
)

func (u *User) Create() {
  u.CreatedAt = time.Now() // FIXME: ERROR. How do I make use of Scan() and Value() here?

  // saving to SQL database
}

func (ts *Timestamp) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    switch t := value.(type) {
    case time.Time:
            var err error
            ts.Timestamp, err = ptypes.TimestampProto(t)
            if err != nil {
                    return err
            }
    default:
            return fmt.Errorf("Not a protobuf Timestamp")
    }
    return nil
}

func (ts Timestamp) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
        return ptypes.Timestamp(ts.Timestamp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scanner and valuer interfaces are not really things you'll use yourself, not when it comes to storing custom types in a DB, at least. I'll first cover the use of the `Scan()` and `Value()` functions, then I'll address your issues.

When you get a `sql.Row` result, and want to assign (scan) the values from the result set into your variables of a custom type. The docs show the `sql.Row.Scan()` function takes 0 or more arguments of type `interface{}`, basically anything. ([check docs here](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan)).

In the list of supported types into which values can be scanned, the last line is the important one:

> any type implementing Scanner (see Scanner docs)

With the function `func (ts *Timestamp) Scan(value interface{}) error {`, the `Timestamp` type now implements the `Scanner` interface, thus allowing `sql.Row` to assign values to this type. The documentation for the `Scanner` interface is located right below the docs for `Scan()`, which I linked above.

Of course, that helps you to read values from the DB, gets you nowhere when it comes to storing these types. For that, you need the `Valuer` interface. In case you haven't guessed it yet, the `func (ts Timestamp) Value() (driver.Value, error)` function indeed makes it so your `Timestamp` type implements this interface. The documentation for the `driver.Valuer` interface can be found [here](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer), all the way at the bottom.

The point of the `Valuer` interface is to allow a way to convert *any* type to a `driver.Value`, that the driver can work with and store in the DB (again: [docs here](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Value)).

---

### Fixing the issues

First up, I'm goign to have to assume your protoc output is written to the `v1` package. If it isn't, it's not going to work very well for you.

The offending line is indeed the one you marked out:

```
u.CreatedAt = time.Now()
```

First up, `User.CreatedAt` is of type `Timestamp`, which is in and of itself a message containing a single timestamp. To set the `CreatedAt` time to `time.Now()`, you need to initialise the `CreatedAt` field correctly:

```
u.CreatedAt = &Timestamp{
    Timestamp: ptypes.TimestampNow(), // this returns a PROTOBUF TYPE!
}
```

You *are* doing this in your `Scan` and `Value`  functions already, so I really don't get why you didn't do it here...

---

### Advice

If the protoc output is indeed written to the `v1` package, I really, really would remove the `User.Create()` function. In fact, I'd outright kill it. Your protocol buffers are used for communication. Exposing your program via RPC's. It's an API. These `message` types are essentially request and response objects (glorified DTO's if you will). You're adding this `Create` function to it, which turns them into AR types. It makes your protobuf package unusable. The beauty of gRPC is that you generate golang, C++, Python, ... code that others can use to call your program. If you make your gRPC package dependent on a database, as you are doing, I personally would never, ever use it.

Comment: Appreciate your response! 'If you make your gRPC package dependent on a database' - good point, I'll move this logic out of gRPC package.